# jQuery Fileupload filter display according to mySQL query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload

Hi i have successfully saved to mySQL database the files uplaoded using jQuery-PHP [FileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#download) with the answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534530/how-use-jquery-file-upload-php-with-database-in-last-reliz) as guide. Now my questiion is, is it possible to only just show the images from my database according to the users who uploaded the imgs? since i also save the users along with the filename.? I dont have idea on how to do it, or whant and where to insert the codes, or is it possible.

EDITED:
I have now idea where it initialize the loading of image

```
protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
    if ($this->is_valid_file_object($file_name)) {
        $file = new stdClass();
        $file->name = $file_name;
        $file->size = $this->get_file_size(
            $this->get_upload_path($file_name)
        );
        $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
        foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
            if (!empty($version)) {
                if (is_file($this->get_upload_path($file_name, $version))) {
                    $file->{$version.'_url'} = $this->get_download_url(
                        $file->name,
                        $version
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        $this->set_file_delete_properties($file);
        return $file;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now i want to insert this mySql query which filter the images that will only show, but i don't know how.

```
SELECT desc FROM images WHERE userid=1
```

Comment: Yes its possible. the query will be for logged-in user **select `image` from table_anme where user = logged_in_user**

Comment: jQuery Upload will just display all the uploaded images, what i want is to filter it. but i dont know how.